# Lua 5.2 new binary library problem

Tags: binary, lua

Okay, so I decided to try out Lua 5.2 today.
I was really interested in the new binary library called *bit*. Some of the functions run lightning fast compared to what I can make on my own, mainly because they've been implemented on the C side of Lua. Take the binary XOR function, it runs 34 times faster than my Lua implementation of XOR.

So, my dilemma is:
I think there's a bug in the *binary* functions already

```
print(bit.bnot(0)) --> 4294967295
```

That's correct, because 4294967295 is 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 in binary

However,

```
print(bit.band(4294967295, 65535)) --> 0
```

Which is wrong, or atleast I think it should be.
65535 in binary is 11111111 11111111.
When I use *bit.band* in the afore mentioned situation shouldn't 65535 be returned ?

I'm using Lua 5.2.0-work2 precompiled binaries from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.2-work2/Executables/)

Comment: It is not Lua 5.2.2, it is Lua 5.2.0-work2

Comment: Try Lua 5.2 alpha, which you can get at http://www.lua.org/work/

Comment: @Alexander; Okay, but that doesn't solve my problem.
@lhf; I'm pretty sure I'm using that version, just a precompiled distribution

Comment: the library name is bit32 in the alpha release

Comment: So there's a different release ? Is there a precompiled release ? I'm unsure about compiling everything myself...

Comment: You're using Lua 5.2.0-work2. You need to switch to the alpha, found at lua.org/work

Comment: @Jason, there are instructions for building Lua 5.2.0 (alpha) at http://www.lua.org/work/doc/#install

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked at the Lua 5.2 releases at all, but if your primary interest is in binary operations, there is a BitOp module for Lua 5.1 [here](http://bitop.luajit.org/) which is source compatible with the native implementations provided by LuaJit.